# Finding a common interior point to two polygons

Tags: computational-geometry, polygons, non-convex, geometry-class-library

Suppose I have overlapping polygons. Neither is necessarily convex. What's an efficient algorithm to find a point interior to both of them and not on either's boundary?

Assuming that they overlap, and our polygons are defined by their sets of vertices in 3D.

Comment: 2D, 3D, nD? Is it predefined that the polygons actually overlap?

Comment: Yes, we're assuming they overlap.

Comment: @Amit if they're >2D, then either they're coplanar and the problem can be reduced to 2D, nonintersecting which is trivial, or intersect along a line which reduces the problem to 1D.

Comment: @Sneftel - you're right of course, but that doesn't change the importance of the question if you want to provide a complete answer. (Unfortunately, Mr. Taylor decided not to answer that part)

Comment: "Overlapping" is meaningless for 3D polygons.

Comment: I'm assuming they're coplanar and that their borders intersect. I think that's a pretty meaningful notion of "Overlapping".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variant of the [Vatti polygon clipping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatti_clipping_algorithm) can be used. Vatti's algorithm is a scanline algorithm, which basically means scan over the vertices of both polygons, from (say) left to right, as well as over any intersections between their boundaries. Between the vertical lines passing through any consecutive two of these "events", you then examine the trapezoids/triangles created by the polygons. Once you find a trapezoid which is part of both, you can just output its centroid.

[image]

Comment: Can these easily extended to being an algorithm that finds the overlapping polygon?

Comment: Sure! I mean, that's what Vatti's algorithm does -- the "just find a centroid" thing is my simplification for the "I just want one point" use-case. Note, however, that the intersection region may consist of *multiple* non-connected polygons.

Comment: Oh, and if you don't want to do the work yourself (and scanline algorithms are notoriously fiddly to implement properly), check out [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php).